# Laravel 4 - Dynamic checkboxes

Tags: forms, laravel

I am currently building a webapp in laravel 4 which is used to register measurements. What I am wondering is if there is any way to do a query and check if a specific task is done for that day, and if it is the checkbox for that should disappear, then reappear the next day until it has been checked and saved.

I apologize if this is a little vague, couldn't figure out a better way to describe it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have your task stored in a data base, let's say you have a task table and a Task model, you can get the list of your tasks that satisfy certain conditions (ex: task not done) then make a check box for each one:

```
<?php $tasks = User::where('done', '=', false)->get() ?>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'tasks')) }}
    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        {{Form::checkbox('task', $task->id, true)}}
    @endforeach
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I was thinking more along these lines:
    `@foreach($complete as $done)
      @if($done->tasks[0]->title == 'D_Slamsuge_Pl_Bass')
        @if(!is_null($done->value))
        {{ 'Utført' }}
        @else
        {{ Form::checkbox('D_Slamsuge_Pl_Bass', 'Utført')  }}
      @endif
      @endif
    @endforeach`

But this way, I could not for the life of me make the checkbox appear.

Comment: you're welcome, it depends on your model, but the main idea is there. you can check the answer if it was helpful:)